# I cant send emails in Oracle Apex 20

Tags: oracle, email, scheduler, apex

Oracle APEX 20.1 ON Windows Server.
Sending mail worked well and stopped.
Message after mail.queue.push:
Ajax call returned server error ORA-27492: unable to run job "APEX_200200"."ORACLE_APEX_MAIL_QUEUE": scheduler unavailable for Execute PL/SQL Code.

After login to INTERNAL I see, that any job in scheduler doesn't work.
Any of google search didn't help.
Any ideas?

After click [Send all mail] from queue - all emails are send.
It looks like sheduler doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely cause is someone turned off the scheduler (possibly for patching etc) and forgot to turn it back on.

Check the current value for 'job_queue_processes'. If its zero, then you'll need to set it to something >0 for the scheduler to run, eg

```
alter system set job_queue_processes = 10;
```